# PhoneBook Coding Gone Wrong

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code:

## PhoneAddressBook

```
def openphonebook():
root.withdraw()
global SaveName, SavePhone

def add_contact():
    SaveName = InputtedName.get()
    SavePhone = InputtedNumber.get()
    try:
        integer_result = int(SavePhone)
    except ValueError:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Error", "Not a Valid Number")
    else:
        addressBook = open(username +".c", "a")
        addressBook.write(SaveName + " " + SavePhone + "\n")
        addressBook.close()
        ShowContent.insert(END, SaveName + '     ' + SavePhone)

def delete_contact():
    selection = ShowContent.curselection()
    ShowContent.delete(selection[0])

AddressBook = Tk()
AddressBook.geometry("700x700")
AddressBook.configure(background="#00d6d6")

Inputs = Frame(AddressBook)
Inputs.configure(background="#00d6d6")
Inputs.pack()

Label(Inputs, text="Name:", bg="#00d6d6").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=15)
InputtedName = StringVar()
nameofPerson = Entry(Inputs, textvariable=InputtedName, highlightbackground="#00d6d6")
nameofPerson.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

Label(Inputs, text="Phone:", bg="#00d6d6").grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W, pady=15)
InputtedNumber = StringVar()
phoneofPerson = Entry(Inputs, textvariable=InputtedNumber, highlightbackground="#00d6d6")
phoneofPerson.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)

ButtonLayout = Frame(AddressBook)
ButtonLayout.pack()
ButtonLayout.configure(bg="#00d6d6", pady=25)
AddButton = Button(ButtonLayout, text=" Add Contact ", highlightbackground="#00d6d6", command=add_contact)
UpdateButton = Button(ButtonLayout, text="Update Contact", highlightbackground="#00d6d6")
DeleteButton = Button(ButtonLayout, text="Delete Contact", highlightbackground="#00d6d6", command=delete_contact)
AddButton.pack(side=LEFT, padx=3)
UpdateButton.pack(side=LEFT, padx=3)
DeleteButton.pack(side=LEFT, padx=3)
global SaveName, SavePhone

DisplayedDetails = Frame(AddressBook)
DisplayedDetails.pack()
Scrolling = Scrollbar(DisplayedDetails, orient=VERTICAL)
global ShowContent
ShowContent = Listbox(DisplayedDetails, yscrollcommand=Scrolling.set, height=20, width=50, )
Scrolling.config(command=ShowContent.yview)
Scrolling.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
ShowContent.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

AddressBook.mainloop()

root.mainloop()
```

As for the error i am getting i input a number such as "336783" i still for some reason still manage to get the messagebox any ideas how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, as a reminder, you should only ever have one call to .mainloop which means you should only have one instance of Tk. If you want other windows, use TopLevel not Tk

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem. Also see [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I haven't had a close look at your code, but you need to fix the indentation of `openphonebook`. Correct indentation is vital in Python. Why do you have `global` statements outside functions? They need to go inside the functions that want to modify the specified global variables.